# Формат поля типа datetime по умолчанию

Tags: doctrine2

В сущности есть поле created_at типа datetime. При сохранении мы получаем нормальную дату в базе - 2018-05-03 12:00:00. Когда делаю запрос в базе, то мне возвращается та же самая дата в том же формате. Когда делаю запрос через getConnection->executeQuery() то дата возвращается в таком формате:2018-05-03Т12:00:00. Можно ли сменить это на обычный Y-m-d H:i:s, а топ приходится создавать объект DateTime, а потом через format выводить дату и так для каждой строки в цикле